# Difference between strings returning remote IP with node js

Tags: node.js

I have stumbled upon the following code:

```
return req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] ||
        req.connection.remoteAddress ||
        req.socket.remoteAddress ||
        req.connection.socket.remoteAddress;
```

I know it is supposed to return the ip where the request came from. But I'd like to know the difference between connection.remoteAddress, socket.remoteAddress, connection.socket.remoteAddress and headers['x-forwarded-for'].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`req.headers['x-forwarded-for']` checks for the HTTP header [`x-forwarded-for`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For), which is a header that is usually set by reverse proxies when they pass a request to the web server.

The scenario is that clients/browsers connect to the proxy, and the proxy connects to the web server. However, because the web server is interested in the IP-address of the client, and not the IP-address of the proxy, this information has to be passed from proxy to web server somehow. That's done by using this header (or with the more recent `Forwarded` header). It's probably better to rely on a module like [`forwarded-http`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forwarded-http) to properly handle the different proxy headers that are used to pass client-IP's.

`req.connection.remoteAddress` and `req.socket.remoteAddress` refer to the exact same thing, because both `req.connection` and `req.socket` are the same object. That object is a [`net.Socket`](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_class_net_socket) instance that represents the (HTTP) connection. That instance has a [`.remoteAddress`](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_remoteaddress) property.

`req.connection.socket` may be something that was used in older Node.js versions; in current versions it doesn't seem to exist.